# I want to get the latitude and longitude from the Gmap control into textboxes

Tags: asp.net, javascript, google-maps

I tried with the following but it doesn't work

```
var txtlat=document.getElementById('TextBox1').value=GMap1.getCenter().lat();
var txtlong=document.getElementById('TextBox2').value=GMap1.getCenter().lng();
```

It gives a JavaScript error as "Object doesn't support this property or method".

How can i do this????

I really need help...

Thank you!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5._Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="GMaps" namespace="Subgurim.Controles" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <cc1:GMap ID="GMap1" runat="server" 
            Key="ABQIAAAAs98ZVKM_IHFkRP_EavW_DhT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxQGoS16N7wYnBPhgtjTxMaUVN58kA" />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var txtlat=document.getElementById('TextBox1').value=GMap1.getCenter().lat();
    var txtlong=document.getElementById('TextBox2').value=GMap1.getCenter().lng();

    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post more code, particularly how GMap1 is created?

Comment: Above post shows how i attempted to do that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer forgot to mention here so the answer was very simple

`Msg1` and `Msg2` are DIV tags

```
protected string Gmap1_Click(object s, Subgurim.Controles.GAjaxServerEventArgs e)
        {
         return "document.getElementById('Msg1').innerHTML="
+ e.point.lat.ToString() + ";" +    "document.getElementById('Msg2').innerHTML="
+ e.point.lng.ToString();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

**2nd UPDATE:** Further to the updated question, you also have another problem with the server-side textbox controls. They cannot be referenced from JavaScript using `document.getElementById()` as you are doing.

You may either use normal HTML controls: `<input type="text" id="textbox1" />` or else you would have to use something like `document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>')` to reference the textbox from JavaScript.

---

**1st UPDATE:** Further to the comments, the examples below have been updated to return the lat/lng of where the mouse is clicked.

---

You may want to check out the following examples, which have been tested to work correctly:

Using the [v3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps getCenter()</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
  <input type="text" id="textbox1" />
  <input type="text" id="textbox2" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.55, -25.75),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      if (event.latLng) {
        document.getElementById('textbox1').value = event.latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById('textbox2').value = event.latLng.lng();
      }
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the [v2 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps getCenter()</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body onunload="GUnload()"> 
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div> 
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" />

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      var centerPoint = new GLatLng(35.55, -25.75);
      map.setCenter(centerPoint, 2);

      GEvent.addListener(map,"click", function(overlay, latlng) {     
        if (latlng) { 
          document.getElementById('textbox1').value = latlng.lat();
          document.getElementById('textbox2').value = latlng.lng();
        }
      });
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot from the above examples:

[image: Google Maps getCenter()]

Comment: Hello Daniel I tried this.Its getting 35.55 and -25.75 on page load.What i want is to get the latitude and longitude in to textboxes ,of a point when the user clicked on the map and also why are u using 
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
Can't i simple drag and drop the Gmap controller that i have added to my toolbox as...
<%@ Register assembly="GMaps" namespace="Subgurim.Controles" tagprefix="cc1" %>
<cc1:GMap ID="GMap1" runat="server" />
.Im still having the problem.
Thank you!

Comment: @chamara: Updated the examples to give the lat/lng of the point where the mouse is clicked... As to the `<script>` tag, I don't have experience using the ASP.NET controls for Google Maps, but I guess what you are doing is correct if you get the map working on your web page.

Answer (score 1):

Did you confirm the value returned from getCenter is not null?  It should be a LatLng object, but maybe it's returning null... are you sure the center has been set yet?  Also, what object type is GMap1?  How do you create that object?

Comment: Hello Brian,
I'm sorry.i'm new to this google maps environment.I can't understand exactly what u are telling.Gmap1 is the ID of the Gmap controller.I still haven't resolved this.
Thank you!

Comment: See @Daniel's sample, do you conform to that setup of the GMap control?